# plotting a curve in logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a curve in logarithmic space. My problem is this: the logarithmic scale in Matlab ignores some of my data points, which are the beginning and ending points.
What should I do to sole this problem?
I have attached my data and my Matlab figure.

Thank you all!
[image: Curve]

You can download the needed data to plot the curve here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmaut5tj37ag5ps/matlab.rar?dl=0

Comment: You should not use links when posting your question.  Please try and reduce the data to an [mcve] that will fit in the question.  Also the image link should have an `!` in front so it gets inlined (i.e. `![Curve][1]`, not `[Curve][1]`)

Comment: Your `x` is `0` for index 1 to 992. After that, there are the 11 plotted points from index 993 to 1004. Where do you expect `x` to be plotted for values of `log(0) = -Inf`? Your plot command seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I think just the scale is logarithmic not the values.
So I xepect to see (0,1) point not log(1) or log(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A logarithmic scale, as you can see from your figure, takes values from small base 10 exponents, to large ones. Negative values are ignored because they cannot be expressed using a logarithm. "zero" values occur at the "infinite" left of the graph, so essentially they are also ignored.

So while I agree when you say "the scale is logarithmic, not the values", there is still no way for you to plot a 0 point on a logarithmic axis, because that would correspond to an axis point at minus infinity (i.e. [image] on your axis).

Btw, I think a better plot for your data is semilogx. This will preserve one more datapoint, since 0 values on the y-axis are fine, and your graph looks more readable.

[image]